# AttributeError - 'User' object has no attribute 'projeto' - Django

Tags: python, django, multi-tenancy

Sou novo em Django e tenho uma dúvida. Fiz um sistema que salva os conteúdos do  respectivo usuário logado. Assim, cada usuário terá seu próprio conteúdo ao visualizar (sistema multi-tenant).

Contudo, tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro

```
AttributeError at /projeto/visualizarProjeto/
'User' object has no attribute 'projeto'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/projeto/visualizarProjeto/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'projeto'
```

Segue meu model

```
class Projeto(models.Model):
    nomeProjeto = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    descricao = HTMLField()
    dtInicio = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    deadline = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    nomeSprint = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Minha view

```
class ProjetoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Projeto
    fields = ['nomeProjeto',
              'descricao',
              'dtInicio',
              'deadline',
              'nomeSprint',
              'status',
             ]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return super(ProjetoCreate, self).form_valid(form)



@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProjetoList(ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    model = Projeto

    def get_queryset(self):
        usuarioLogado = self.request.user.projeto.user
        return Projeto.objects.filter(User=usuarioLogado)
```

Como o respectivo usuário logado poderá ver apenas seu conteúdo cadastrado, sem dar esse erro?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Como você não definiu o parâmetro `related_name` no atributo `user` do modelo `Projeto`, acredito que você precise fazer a *backreference* pelo atributo `projeto_set` ("*<classe>*_set"), que é usado por padrão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
def get_queryset(self):
        usuarioLogado = self.request.user
        return Projeto.objects.filter(user=usuarioLogado)
```